# Test always gives "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, exception, mstest

I am currently writing a unit test for class methods but accessor always throwing an exception.

Consider the following test method:

```
namespace GSVMTestCase
{    
    [TestClass]
    public class GatewaySettingsViewModelTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        [DeploymentItem("SmartGatewayUABL.dll")]
        public void AddGatewayTest1()
        {
            GatewaySettingsViewModel_Accessor target = new GatewaySettingsViewModel_Accessor(); // error occurs here
            target.GatewayIPAddress = null;
            target.AddGateway();
            Assert.AreEqual(TextStrings.TxtErrInvalidIP, target.ErrorMessage);
        }}}
}
```

always throwing exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Are you sure it is that line? Note that *we can't see* `GatewaySettingsViewModel_Accessor`, so I'm not sure how we should comment...

Comment: Isn't the exception thrown from the `GatewaySettingsViewModel_Accessor()` constructor?

Comment: Your edit isn't helpful; you say the error is when calling the `GatewaySettingsViewModel_Accessor` constructor. The one thing you haven't shown is: the `GatewaySettingsViewModel_Accessor` constructor.

Comment: yes GatewaySettingsViewModel_Accessor  throwing exception

Answer (score 0):

hey got the solution of the problem while calling constructor there was configuration file was missing.So after adding app.config it get resolved. Thanks everyone for your valueable review

Answer (score 0):

Given the naming scheme of what you're doing here, it looks as though you're employing some trickery to test this assembly.  If this "SmartGatewayUABL.dll" is *your* assembly, then I'd add a project reference to the test assembly and test it without the deployment item stuff.

If it's not your assembly, then one would have to wonder why you're seeking to test a class from it.  This is generally not desirable if you want to persist and maintain the test.  If you're just experimenting, I'd suggest considering your experiment here at an end and trying something else.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clearer for other people with this issue. Your main project can get data from the back-end to the front-end because a connectionString must be setup in its web.config file. So, you need to create a Application Configuration File called *.config in your unit test project and paste this connectionString inside.